# display text of label for 10 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

im using windows form application..using c# . i have a label that displays some text when i click a buttom. now i want the label to display its text only for 10 seconds and later it should get disabled.

Comment: Is it Windows Forms or ASP.NET? The post says one, but the tags say another...

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), set it to 10 seconds when the form loads (or whenever you need it to).

In the timer Tick event, you can disable the label control (or set its text to `string.Empty`, or whatever you need). You will also need to stop the timer at that point, or it will keep firing every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

there is a control name timer.you can find it in toolbox use that control and set time in it and assign a work in its code body.it will work

here is the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

If you got solution from my answer then click my answer and vote me.thanx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Timer class examples in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).